# InstantClick not binding to dynamic href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bind

I am currently using http://instantclick.io, however the plugin is not binding my dynamically created links.

PHP Response

```
$json['alert'] = array(
      'type'      =>  'success',
      'content'   =>  'Success! Your new thread has been posted, you can visit      it <a href="' . site_url_in . 'forums/thread/' . $id . '">here</a>'
);
```

jQuery form handler

```
$.post(url, form, function(data){
            //Lets do awesomeness
            console.log('Data: ' + data);
            console.log('Form: ' + form);
            dm.commander.init(data);
        });
```

Commander.init reads in the response, and the response above would execute the `alert()`function within `dm.commander`

```
alert: function(message)
{
    $("#messages").empty();
    $("#messages").prepend('<div class="alert alert-'+message['type']+'">'+message['content']+'</div>');
//        this.scrollTo('messages');

},
```

As you can see the PHP response sends out an alert with a link in it. The form then processes it and returns alert() which prepends a div to #messages

And the jQuery that binds is

```
$(document).one('click', 'a', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    InstantClick.init(100);
```

The above works with normal links that are already on the page however it doesn't work with the link PHP generates and jQuery prepends.

Though I cannot specifically delegate to `#messages` due to other functions in the future could append to say `#content`.

Is there anyway to bind instantclick to dynamically created links such as above.

And yes I have researched and couldn't find an answer that worked.

Comment: Are you calling instantclick after those functions?

Comment: Instantclick is the last thing to be initiated, I have also tried reinitialising after the form process to no avail

Comment: Odd, that's the only thing I can think of right now.

Comment: `$(document).one('click', 'a', function(e) {` That should be .on(), I take it?

Comment: @Thoronwen No, one is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only initializing the InstantClick on page load. It will then apply itself on all the link currently in the DOM tree. Then when you add new links to the DOM tree, these are not automagically added to the InstantClick. Try initializing the InstantClick at the end of the AJAX alert function.

After reading NoGray's answer I think you do want to change from .one to .on. Also, this needs to be reinitiated as well:

```
alert: function(message)
{
    $("#messages").empty();
    $("#messages").prepend('<div class="alert alert-'+message['type']+'">'+message['content']+'</div>');
//        this.scrollTo('messages');
    $(document).unbind('click').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
        console.log('clicked');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    InstantClick.init(100);
},
```

I got to admit this feels a bit dirty. Just initializing it again, but I couldn't find any documentation about some sort of destroy or reinit functions. So this is my best guess.

The original bottom code fixed:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
InstantClick.init(100);
```

Comment: clicked does get displayed now in console log however after that nothing happens.

Comment: Since you're doing `e.preventDefault();` and I havn't used InstantClick myself, I presume that InstantClick is suppose to fire the link preloaded on click?

Answer (score 2):

actually for dynamically created DOM elements you need to use **on** instead of **one**.

```
$(document).off("click",'a').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    console.log('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

thanks